# Group prices are cached (Lesti_Fpc) and displayed to all visitors

Tags: magento-1.9, group-price, caching

We realized that the group price are cached and after log out, regular customer can see the discount, till we refresh the cache. How to solve this?

Comment: Can you expand on what you are using for caching. This sounds like it may be a full page caching matter - varnish perhaps? In which case things like price need to be hole punched to get the customer specific data.

Comment: Lesti_Fpc is what we use

Comment: I think you have to clear caches inside System->Cache Management

Comment: I have done that, it fix the issue, but again after login as special customer and log out, the special prices are visible to all

Comment: Please post the solution you found as an answer

Comment: I posted it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Lesti_FPC's system.xml file change the "0" to "1" in below section to activate it.

```
<customer_groups>
      <label>Customer Group Caching</label>
      <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>          
      <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
      <sort_order>70</sort_order>
      <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
      <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
     <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
</customer_groups>
```

Then go to System => Configuration => Advanced => System => Lesti FPC, set the Customer Group Caching to YES.

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 1):

It seems flat catalog is enabled in your website:

Inside **System->Index Management->Product Prices ->Reindex Data**

also set mode as **Update on save**

Comment: That's also not permanent solution. I tried it, it fixes till the moment special customer is not logged in,after log out still special prices are visible